# DrawImage is slow, lockbits to the rescue?

Tags: c#, powershell, image-manipulation, lockbits

I've read many C# tutorials on using lockbits to manipulate images, but I just don't know how to apply this info into PowerShell.

This is the problem:

$image1's height is 2950 pixels. $image2's height is 50 px taller, 3000 pixels. I need to fit $image2 into $image1 and I can skip $image2's first 49 px lines. So in pseudocode:

```
 For(y=0... For(x=0.... { image1(x,y) = image2(x,y+50) } ....))
```

The PowerShell script below works, but does not work very fast:

```
$rect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 0, 0, $image1.width, $image1.height
$image1drawing.drawimage($image2, 
                         $rect, 
                         0, 50, $image2.width, ($image2.height - 50), 
                         $graphicalUnit)
```

The pages I've found, such as this ([Not able to successfully use lockbits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202606/problem-with-using-lockbits)) or this (https://web.archive.org/web/20121203144033/http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm) are in "plain English" but how to convert this concept into PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the correct approach. Using `DrawImage` will be faster that copying the pixels one by one.
Some suggestions to make it faster:

1. Try using Image.Clone to copy a rectangle from the original image, this will result in the smallest number of objects you need to create.
2. Make sure you use the same `PixelFormat` as the original image (faster copying). There is a `PixelFormat` attribute in `Image`.
3. Most important: accessing `Width` and `Height` takes a long time so save them to a local variable for reuse. If you know them before hand that's a good way to speed-up things.
4. Don't expect miracles at a width to height ratio of 4:3 each image is 3932 * 2950 * 3(assuming 24 bit RGB) = 33Mb per image. That's a lot of data, you may easily be be trying to copy a few gigs depending on how many images you have.

You are better off writing a simple [cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878321(v=vs.85).aspx) and using it in your PowerShell script.

BTW in case you are still interested:

Using `lockbits` in C# (as per your examples) relies on [unsafe context and using pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx). I don't believe PowerShell has access to unsafe context.
You can manipulate unmanaged data without using an unsafe context by using the  [`Marshall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.100).aspx) class; specifically the `Read` and `Write` methods (and you might be able to speed things up with the `Copy` method at expense of memory).
PowerShell was not meant as a replacement for .Net generic languages, that's what CmdLets are for.

Comment: Good tips, thank you. You motivated me into doing some more tweaking first and re-checking my loops, variable usage and such. While browsing topics of "set-put-pixel / drawimage/ performance" I mistook lockbits as the universal solution to all programming/graphic problems.

Comment: `LockBits` does not require unsafe operations if you use `Marshal.Copy` to get the bytes out.

Comment: @Nyerguds yes you are correct, thanks for pointing that out.

It is the C# examples linked by the original poster that used unsafe context not lockbits.

The next paragraph mentions the Marshall class as a work around but I was probably not clear enough:

You can either use Marshall.Read/Marshall.Write to access the locked bits directly or Marshall.Copy to copy the locked bits to managed memory, manipulate them and copy them back again.
In any case writing a cmdlet instead of using a Powershell script is probably the best approach.